# Python `typing.cast` method vs colon type hints

Tags: python, type-hinting

What is the advantage of using the Python `typing.cast` method

```
x = cast(str, x)
```

instead of using type hint/colon notation?

```
x: str
```

I've seen the use of the cast method in codebases but don't have an apparent reason to use it instead of type hint notation, which is more concise.

Comment: I don't think `x = cast(str, x)` is a clear example of what you're trying to ask about. Strictly speaking, that's exactly one of 1) a `NameError` (if `x` isn't assigned), a type checking error (if the type of `x` isn't compatible with `str`), or completely redundant (if `x` is already compatible with `str`). Would `x: str = <expr>` vs `x = cast(str, <expr>)` be clearer?

Answer (score 4):

I will answer you through a well-written example:

```
def get_name(canReturnName: bool) -> str | None:
    in_name = input('Enter your name: ')
    return in_name if canReturnName else None

def do_something_with_name() -> None:
    name: str = get_name(True)
    print(name.capitalize())
```

Here, you'd expect Pyright or mypy to say that `name`'s type is `str`, even if the return type of `get_name` is `str | None`, but this is not the case:

if the function you are calling (in this case `get_name`) has a return type, the column notation type will be ignored completely, and Pyright will tell you that you can't call `.capitalize` on a name, as it could be `None`

In this case though, you are completely sure that name will be `str` and not `None`, so you can use `cast`, like such:

```
def do_something_with_name() -> None:
    name: str = cast(str, get_name(True))
    print(name.capitalize())
```

`get_name`'s value will be unchanged, but static type checkers will treat them as the first argument's type.

in fact, as [python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) states, the cast function does in fact nothing at all.

It can be defined with the new Python 3.12 generics as such:

```
def cast[T](var: object) -> T:
    return var

cast[str](get_name(True))
```

Comment: Good example. Makes it clear how `cast` lets you inject programmer knowledge about the runtime behavior of functions into the type system. Though  arguably `get_name` could be even more well written if it was [`overload`ed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) for `Literal[True]`/`Literal[False]` :).

Comment: I agree. I like this answer the best.

Comment: @Brian61354270 Possibly it’s just me, but if I were to see your suggested syntax in code, I would really have to expend way too many brain cycles to understand what, at heart, is a very trivial bit of code.  Python is not Rust, typing is meant to *help* people, and delivers no value to compilers.  It’s no excuse to make things overcomplex in other words.

Comment: Unfortunately, in your last example with a `cast()` that's generic over `T`, you cannot subscript functions even if they're generic: `cast[str](get_name(True))`
Results in: `TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: That seems indeed the case, however, I can't manage to find any example for generics functions in python 3.12, and I thought this would give an idea. I'd be grateful to see an example for this!

Answer (score 2):

I think it's simply for inlining a type annotation on an expression. The [PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#casts) contains the following line:

```
return cast(str, a[index])
```

There is no variable to annotate here, since it's `a[index]` that's being "casted". Without `cast`, you'd need to either ensure that `a` is properly typed so it can be inferred, or create a new variable just to use `:`-style annotations.

Comment: Another very common use case is inside comprehensions, where creating a new variable isn't even an option. For example `[foo(cast(str, a)) for a in iterable]`. This comes up pretty often when using a [certain popular array processing package](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/), which uses `Hashable` for keys that the user can guarantee will be `str`s

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding the concept.

`x = cast(str, x)` isn't about typing the left x.  It’s about telling the left x to accept whatever the existing x on the right already has typing as being a string and not complaining.

Let’s split into 2 vars instead.

```
x = apply("abc",str.upper)

y : myUpperStringType = cast(x, myUpperStringType)
```

I.e. you “vouch” for the right hand x being acceptable to y’s typing requirements for the purpose of type analysis. Maybe x is the result of an external API call?  You know reading the above x will be an upper string.

Cast is an escape clause to tell the scanners not to bug you. Matter of opinion rather than hard fact:  IMHO, using it it as you did serves no purpose, you’d be better off tweaking the downstream code to work with x’s *original* typing.  Well, except that the [inlining answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77260204/1394353) also makes sense.

Runtime `cast` is a no-op, it just returns the variable.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, we usually use hints to tell the computer what kind of data (like numbers or text) a variable should hold. The typing.cast thing is like a way to be extra clear about this. It's helpful when you want to make your code more readable by saying, "Even though it might seem like this is one type, I want you to treat it as another type." But for most cases, just using the regular hints with colons (:) is easier to understand.

Answer (score -1):

`Type Hints` provides a way to specify expected types for variables, function parameters, return values. They don't impact runtime behavior. they inform developers and linters/static type checkers about the expected types.

`typing.cast` is a function that helps inform the type checker that you are deliberately and knowingly converting a variable to a specific type. It's a way of overriding the inferred type that the type checker might deduce. It's merely a hint for the type checker.

Example:
Suppose you have a variable `value` that could be either an `int` or a `str`. After a certain check, you know it's a `str`, but the type checker does not. You might use `cast` to inform the type checker of this:

```
from typing import Union, cast

def process_value(value: Union[int, str]) -> str:
    if isinstance(value, str):
        value_str = cast(str, value)  # Inform type checker of the type
        return value_str.upper()
    else:
        return str(value)
```

References:

- [Type Hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)
- [typing.cast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast)

Comment: This doesn't say why you think `value_str = cast(str, value)` is an improvement over `value_str: str = value` (which I don't think has much popular support). It's also completely superfluous, since the `isinstance(value, str)` guard already narrowed `value` to `str`. Just ask your favorite type-checker to `reveal_type(value)`